# LINQ group by date like today, tomorrow into keyed list

Tags: linq, windows-phone-8.1, group-by

I have a database on windows phone application. I have to-do items and I want to list them grouped like "Today", "Tomorrow" etc. I have a keyedlist based on that and I'm using longlistselector with groups to show data.

I have a date column on database and want to group items by using it. Comparing date with it I want to group items on calling from database like "Today", "Tomorrow", "Other" etc. I tried some let functions but it always throws exception. How can I do when calling it with LINQ?

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Comment: Linq;
var tariheGoreGrupla =
                    from hatirlatma in toDoItemsInDB
                    orderby hatirlatma.Due_Date
                    let gun= GetDate(hatirlatma as ToDoItem)
                    group hatirlatma by gun into tariheGore
                    select new KeyedList<string, ToDoItem> tariheGore);
GetDate;

static string GetDate(ToDoItem item)
        {
            if (item.Due_Date > 0)
            {
                return "Bugün";
            }
            else
            {             
                return "Yarın";                
            }
}

Comment: And which exception does that throw?

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: Method 'System.String GetDate(Mind_v0._3.Models.ToDoItem)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: I don't know if my try is right way or there is another way to do that. In my searches I find something like that in microsoft's site and tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to instruct the LINQ query that the local part should be done locally:

```
var tariheGoreGrupla = (from hatirlatma in
                           (from hatirlatmaX in toDoItemsInDB 
                            orderby hatirlatmaX.Due_Date
                            select hatirlatmaX).AsEnumerable()
                       let gun = GetDate(hatirlatma as ToDoItem)
                       group hatirlatma by gun into tariheGore);
```

`AsEnumerable()` means "from this point on, use the local enumerable methods and don't try to convert this into an SQL query".

Comment: is there a syntax error? Visual Studio points that "The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'."

Comment: I went by the code you posted which apparently selected into `KeyedList<string, ToDoItem>` but parentheses were missing and I don't know the constructor to that class.

Comment: Many thanks to you and your kindness. In second query you just forget to put "select hatirlatmaX" at the and of query, problem was that. I'm new to linq but this code is the best way, right? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Yes, that was necessary. I mixed up `orderby` with `group .. by` which as you can see in the big query does not require a `select` clause after it.

Comment: "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause" it says without select and in the code i was shared there is a parentheses before tariheGore, my mistake.